# How to parse request.body data to json dict?

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-rest-framework

```
 if request.method == "PUT":

        qd = QueryDict(request.body)
        print request.body
        myDict = dict(qd.iterlists())
        print str(myDict)
```

I have writen this code in my middleware and getting below output

```
 Content-Disposition: form-data; name="id_list"

 3,4,5
 ------WebKitFormBoundaryXnLHZBd9m8nUWltw Content-Disposition: form-data; name="nanan"

 ananna
 ------WebKitFormBoundaryXnLHZBd9m8nUWltw Content-Disposition: form-data; name="samay"

 samay
 ------WebKitFormBoundaryXnLHZBd9m8nUWltw--

 {u'------WebKitFormBoundaryXnLHZBd9m8nUWltw\r\nContent-Disposition:
 form-data': [u''], u' name':
 [u'"id_list"\r\n\r\n3,4,5\r\n------WebKitFormBoundaryXnLHZBd9m8nUWltw\r\nContent-Disposition:
 form-data',
 u'"nanan"\r\n\r\nananna\r\n------WebKitFormBoundaryXnLHZBd9m8nUWltw\r\nContent-Disposition:
 form-data',
 u'"samay"\r\n\r\nsamay\r\n------WebKitFormBoundaryXnLHZBd9m8nUWltw--\r\n']}
```

How do I get individual fields from raw data ?

Comment: Please read about how to create a minimal, complete and verifiable example, [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Django Rest Framework (what I assume based on tags of your question), you can find PUT request data in `request.data` as mentioned in [Rest Framework docs](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/2-requests-and-responses/#request-objects).

Comment: @Mikhali its not working inside middleware